# Golang Redirect function inside template file fails

Tags: go

As the golang documentation states, a template function has to have at least 1 return parameter, so I think I can rule out template functions already.

So I thought I could just create the function directly on the Content model, but I guess not?

I think the markup below is pretty self explaining (index.tmpl file in root folder):

```
{{$request := .Request}}
{{$response := .Response}}
{{if eq $request.Method "POST"}}
    {{.Redirect "page1" 301}}
{{end}}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{.Title | title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{.Title}}</h1>
    {{.Body}}
    <p>{{.ContentType}}</p>
    <p>{{$request}}</p>
    <p>{{lol}}</p>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="lolcat"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is kinda equivalent to how one would do it in ASP.Net/Razor, but it doesn't work.

The rest of the code is here http://play.golang.org/p/LMKdflA9RS

To test the program locally you need to have:

```
main.go
index.tmpl
page1.tmpl (just use the same as index.tmpl)
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can this be achieved? :-)

**Solution:**

http://play.golang.org/p/b2I_uzjiSH

Thanks to Ainar-G!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logic like this should go into handlers. Templates are for presenting data only. They are not designed to be anything more. Any decisions about what and how to render should be done in the handler code.

With that in mind, here is how you could do that: http://play.golang.org/p/Md5A54rLm7.

You can't write directly to `w` because this will cause it to set response code to 200. You should also register the `redirect` function inside a wrapper because all template functions must return one or two (with error) values. Again, just because you can, it doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I know this very well, but my application is not a fixed one. It's a CMS which need to be as flexible and easy to customize as possible. I know it's not the ideal way to do it this way, but sometimes it's just worth it. Of course I've been thinking I might need to implement this in handlers, but really - this would have been the best way for my specific situation. That's why I did not ask if it's the best way, but how to make this possible. I guess if it isn't, I have no choice  but to make a pipeline for hijacking handlers. But thanks for your answer anyways.

Comment: Curiosity took over me and I decided to check if it would actually work. It did. I added the code that works if you still think this is a good solution.

Comment: 1) buf := &bytes.Buffer{} 2) tpl.ExecuteTemplate(buf, templateName, content) 3) io.Copy(w, buf) did the trick. How did you figure this out? Since ASP.Net Razor is implementing this functionality with c# in views, isn't there situations where it can be justified to do it this way? My app is a CMS, with lots of dynamically added templates, directly or through plugins. Is it really THAT bad practice, or does it make sense to do it this way for flexibility and customizability? It wouldn't be impossible to create handlers and inject those.. Is the performance hit big when using io.Copy?

Comment: By trying things and carefully reading [the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter). Performance is probably not an issue. I'm wary about this because of [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Routing rules should be in a routing config, not scattered around views, shouldn't they? Adding more functions to templates will eventually turn them into a (bad) scripting language. And if you do need a scripting language, why not just use Lua?